# How to encapsulate a very long string in quotation marks?

Tags: vbscript

I want to print a long VBScript program into a file as one string.

```
program_str = " long 200 line program"
```

However, placing quotation marks around so long a string does not work, as it stops recognizing the program as a string as soon as it hits another set of  quotation marks.  Short of separating each line of the program, and concatenating it, how could I take this long program as a string and paste it into a file?

Comment: You need to 'escape' the quotation marks within your program. For VBA that means replacing all quotes `"` with double `""`

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Double any quotes in your string literal:

   ```
   program_str = "This program has a quote like this "" in it."
   ```
2. Use `Chr(34)` to specify a quote in your string literal (requires concatenating):

   ```
   program_str = "This program has a quote like this " & Chr(34) & " in it."
   ```

Comment: Option 2 means you still have to escape single quotes.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner You're right, of course. Spending too much time working in JavaScript lately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include speech marks in a string, you must precede each of them with another quotation mark `"`

e.g.

```
program_str = "He said ""Hello"""
```

Comment: That's a C style escape sequence. VBA requires you to double up quotation marks to escape them ... see my comment.

Comment: There are no type specifiers in VBScript (`Dim quotation as String`) and you cannot declare and initialize in the same statement (unless `Const`).